# Reverse DNS look up in python

Tags: python, dns, dnspython

I am trying to do a reverse lookup in python,

what I did was, give input as [www.fastly.com](http://www.fastly.com)

```
test = dns.resolver.resolve('www.fastly.com.','CNAME', raise_on_no_answer=False)
print (test.rrset)
```

which gives output as,

```
www.fastly.com. 3600 IN CNAME prod.www-fastly-com.map.fastly.net.
```

What I want to do is, give input as `prod.www-fastly-com.map.fastly.net` and get `www.fastly.com`

Please help me , how can I do this, I search other similar questions here, but did'nt get a definite answer.

Thank you and Stay Safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible with DNS. It would require a global database since multiple `CNAME` records can have the same target.

Some projects collect DNS data and provide a more or less complete view of the DNS. The terms passive or active DNS database should give you a good starting point to find them. With these databases it is possible to search for RDATA and/or types, but the databases will be incomplete.